# 'pipenv lock -r' doesn't work through docker-compose run command

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pipenv

I have python container if I'm in the container I can use pipenv for generate a requirements.txt file with :
`pipenv lock -r > python_modules/requirements.txt`

But if I'm not in the container I can't with the command :

```
docker-compose run python pipenv lock -r > python_modules/requirements.txt
```

The requirements file that I get is like this :

```
Usage: [39m[1mpipenv[39m[22m [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

[39m[1mOptions:[39m[22m
  --where                         Output project
                                  home
                                  information.

  --venv                          Output
                                  virtualenv
                                  information.

  -

-py                            Output Python
                                      interpreter
...
```

Comment: Why are you trying to run this via `docker-compose`; can you just run it in a non-Docker development setup?

Comment: I don't have python on my machine and I don't want to install it to have all the advantages of a docker container.
For up the container localy I need to have all the requirements download localy, this command is run in a makefile for  download the requirements localy and don't have to download each time that I start the container

Answer (score 0):

As of [v2022.8.13](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/releases/tag/v2022.8.13) of pipenv, the "old" `lock -r` functionality has been removed.

Going forward, this should be accomplished with:

```
pipenv requirements > requirements.txt
```